# Get-Item Query throws a parse error at the end of position

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I'm trying to retrieve all the items in sitecore content using particular template.

I've tried removing the -Path parameter but that doesn't help. See code below

```
$items = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "master:/sitecore/content//*[@@templatename='Template Name']"
```

The Get-Item should return the results correctly without any errors

Comment: Please [edit] the actual text of errors, verbatim, and don't post images.  Consider reading [ask].  Also, the answer doesn't appear to be related to the original error... I believe you fixed the actual issue in adjusting the contents of that string.

Comment: @gravity - I've updated the question title( this is actually my first one ever ) I'm not sure why you have downvoted it but the original error which I got was related to the end of position 6. I have tried googling  around and couldn't find the answer so I posted the question here. I got both syntaxes for -Query parameter mixed between fast query and the sitecore query. I was hoping it should help someone out there in the wild so posted the solution specific to my error.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging - I think I've found the issue. its the -Query parameter it should have a keyword "fast:" and not "master:" and that fixed it. Hope it helps someone !
Final fixed code should look like:

```
$items = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Query "fast:/sitecore/content//*[@@templatename='Template Name']"
```

Answer (score 0):

Same can be achieved using this as well

```
$items = Get-Item master: -Query "/sitecore/content//*[@@templatename='Template Name']"
```